# Heroku Deploy Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I tried to deploy my simple rails app on Heroku
([deployment logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Md3B.jpg)) but I got and error:

```
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

I did step by step :

1. `git init`
2. `heroku create`
3. `git commit -am ".."`
4. `git push heroku master`

The log says connection built but app not displayed. Any idea where when wrong?

```
  Discovering process types
   Procfile declares types     -> (none)
   Default types for buildpack -> console, rake, web, worker
   Compressing...
   Done: 37.3M
   Launching...
   Released v5
   https://coursecatalog2.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: can you show us your `database.yml` file. Also make sure you have `gem 'pg'` in your gemfile in the production group and `sqlite3` in development/test

Comment: Can you check your app logs with the `heroku logs` command and paste the last 20 lines here?

Comment: If heroku is pulling from a remote git, after you commit your changes, you have to push your changes Just run `git push` after `git commit -m "..."` . After that, push to heroku. `git push heroku master`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked you production group gems ?
Have you included pg gem there ?
do you have any pending migrations ?
check those first and if your db is all setup try to migrate them using from your terminal if you're using heroku CLI

```
 heroku run rake db:migrate
```

or from the console in your application dashboard

Comment: When I run the command, I got : Gem::LoadError: Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'sqlite3'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). But the " gem 'sqlite3' ,'1.3.13' " is under "group :development, :test do"  Why this is happening? The app runs perfectly on local server

Answer (score 0):

Gemfile!

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```